# Mongodb: Update multiple fields of a documents with condition

Tags: mongodb, go

I'm new to mongodb. I have an object which looks like this

```
{
  "_id" : 1,
  "name" : "Alex",
  "quantity" : 10,
  "lastActivityTime" : ISODate("2022-09-01T03:38:29Z"),
  "lastRefreshTime" : ISODate("2022-10-01T20:54:19.618Z"),
  "checking": [1, 2, 3],
}
```

I would like to update this document with the following conditions:

1. If `lastActivityTime` is before a `deadline`, then increase `quantity`.
2. Otherwise, keep `quantity` as it is.

In both cases, I also need to delete a value in the field `checking` (e.g., 3) AND update `lastActivityTime` to the current time.

This is my current code. It works but it need to run `updateOne()` twice. Is there any more efficient way?

```
r, err := s.collection.UpdateOne(ctx,
    bson.M{
        "_id": 1,
        "lastActivityTime": bson.M{"$not": bson.M{"$gte": deadline}}},
    bson.M{
        "$set": bson.M{
            "lastActivityTime":  time.Now(),
        },
        "$inc": bson.M{
            "quantity": 1,
        },
        "$pull": bson.M{
            "checking":       3,
        },
    },
)
if r.MatchedCount == 0 {
    r, err = s.accountTokenCollection.UpdateOne(ctx,
        bson.M{
            "_id": 1,
            "lastActivityTime": bson.M{"$gte": deadline}},
        bson.M{
            "$set": bson.M{
                "lastRefreshedTime": time.Now(),
            },
            "$pull": bson.M{
               "checking":       3,
            },
        },
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the Go equivalent, but you can use the pipelined form of document update, like this:

```
db.collection.update({
  _id: 1
},
[
  {
    "$set": {
      "quantity": {
        $cond: {
          if: {
            $lt: [
              "$lastActivityTime",
              ISODate("2022-09-01T03:38:30Z")
            ]
          },
          then: {
            $sum: [
              "$quantity",
              1
            ]
          },
          else: "$quantity"
        }
      },
      "lastActivityTime": "$$NOW",
      "checking": {
        $filter: {
          input: "$checking",
          as: "item",
          cond: {
            $ne: [
              "$$item",
              3
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

This is the playground [link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/VzSIc0k8EVA).